# How to use regex in Python list

Tags: python, regex, list, split

I need your help because want to use regex on a list to get only the string after my keyword.

`my_list` looks like:

```
 ['Paris, 458 boulevard Saint-Germain', 'Marseille, 29 rue Camille Desmoulins', 'Marseille, 1 chemin des Aubagnens']
```

The regex:

```
re.compile(ur'(?<=rue|boulevard|quai|chemin).*', re.MULTILINE)
```

Expected list after processing:

```
['Saint-Germain', 'Camille Desmoulins', 'des Aubagnens']
```

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your regex does not work in Python, the error it throws is `look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`.

Also, please note that `re.MULTILINE` flag in your regex is redundant as there is no `^` nor `$` to re-define behavior for in the pattern.

Here is the code you can use:

```
import re
lst =  ['Paris, 458 boulevard Saint-Germain', 'Marseille, 29 rue Camille Desmoulins', 'Marseille, 1 chemin des Aubagnens']
p = re.compile(r'.*(?:rue|boulevard|quai|chemin)')
print [p.sub('', x).strip() for x in lst]
```

[IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/4QshSp)

Result:

```
['Saint-Germain', 'Camille Desmoulins', 'des Aubagnens']
```

The `r'.*(?:rue|boulevard|quai|chemin)'` regex matches

- `.*` - 0 or more any character
- `(?:rue|boulevard|quai|chemin)` - 1 of the alternatives delimited with `|`.

and then the matched text is removed with `re.sub`.

*NOTE* you can force whole word matching with `\b` word boundary so that `chemin` was matched and not `chemins`:

```
r'.*\b(?:rue|boulevard|quai|chemin)\b'
```

Answer (score 2):

Lookbehinds need to have a constant width in python regex.
Try this simpler regex instead -

```
>>> regex = re.compile(ur'(?:rue|boulevard|quai|chemin)(.*)', re.MULTILINE)
>>> [re.findall(regex, e)[0].strip() for e in my_list]
['Saint-Germain', 'Camille Desmoulins', 'des Aubagnens']
```

**EDIT:**
Using different lookbehinds can work -

```
(?:(?<=rue)|(?<=boulevard)|(?<=quai)|(?<=chemin))(.*)
```

Example -

```
>>> regex = re.compile(ur'(?:(?<=rue)|(?<=boulevard)|(?<=quai)|(?<=chemin))(.*)', re.MULTILINE)
>>> [re.findall(regex, e)[0].strip() for e in li]
['Saint-Germain', 'Camille Desmoulins', 'des Aubagnens']
```